# SMS API via Raspberry PI

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-2

I want to calculate the temperature and humidity via sense hat integrated with Raspberry Pi 3. 
Is there any free API for SMS available currently?

Answer (score 3):

It's unlikely that you'll find a **free** API for sending text messages, simply because sending them *isn't* cost free.

That said, you're looking for an [SMS Gateway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway). Many US mobile providers [offer free gateways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway#Email_clients) that will convert an email sent to a specific address into a text message to the corresponding telephone number. This may also be the case in other countries, although you will need to check with the providers you wish to communicate with.

Otherwise, you'll need to use a **paid** SMS Gateway, such as [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/sms). Pricing [varies](https://www.twilio.com/sms/pricing/gb) by volume and location, but they do offer a [free trial balance](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223136107-How-does-Twilio-s-Free-Trial-work-) to test with, before you commit to paying per message. They offer libraries for various languages and the [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart) is pretty extensive, which is what you'd expect if you did choose to pay for the service.

Other paid gateways likely have similar pricing structures and features, and you'll need to take a look around the market for the most appropriate for your use case.

Comment: SIM card adaptors with easy to use software?

Comment: +1 for Twilio. They are incredibly developer friendly, they provide examples in a half-dozen languages, for instance.